# Mysql replication does not work with different db engines?

Tags: mysql, replication

We are replicating 1db to other clusters but It is not replicating all the tables. I do not know what is the issue. It always shows replication status synchronized.

Comment: You could look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135666/34007) for a relatively painless way to change all your tables to the InnoDB engine. In MySQL 8, the system tables [have been changed from](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/system-database.html) MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Are you using Galera Cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Currently replication works only with the InnoDB storage engine. Any writes to tables of other types, including system (mysql.) tables are not replicated (this limitation excludes DDL statements such as CREATE USER, which implicitly modify the mysql. tables — those are replicated). There is however experimental support for MyISAM - see the wsrep_replicate_myisam system variable)

Reference [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/).

If you are using innodb as default db engine then use innodb with all tables.

It is the possible cause:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You can fix in this way. Run above on master server.

Comment: _Caution:  This Answer assumes Galera Cluster (PXC) is in use._